# Sort out pairs with same members but different order from list of pairs

Tags: python

From the list

```
l =[(3,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,2)]
```

I want to sort out all second appearances of pairs with the same members in reverse order. I.e., the result should be

```
[(3,4),(2,3)]
```

What's the most concise way to do that in Python?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the resulting tuples are both sorted ascendingly? Or can we also expect different orderings? Also, can we always expect that a each tuple has a reversed "sister"? Will there ever be tuples by themselves?

Comment: Absolutely, no constrictions on the orderings. I just want to get rid of each second tuple with the same pairing in different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if any(y[::-1] == x for y in l[i:])]
Out[23]: [(3, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Expanding the initial list a little bit with different orderings:

```
l =[(3,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,2), (1,3), (3,1)]

[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if any(y[::-1] == x for y in l[i:])]
Out[25]: [(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

And, depending on whether each tuple is guaranteed to have an accompanying "sister" reversed tuple, the logic may change in order to keep "singleton" tuples:

```
l = [(3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 3), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1), (10, 11), (10, 12)]

[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if any(y[::-1] == x for y in l[i:]) or not any(y[::-1] == x for y in l)]
Out[35]: [(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 3), (10, 11), (10, 12)]
```

Comment: the latest line works but is both hardly readable and not "most concise"

Comment: @Guillaume I never said it was the most concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one might do it in a more verbose way:

```
l = [(3,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,2)]
L = []
omega = set([])
for a,b in l:
    key = (min(a,b), max(a,b))
    if key in omega:
        continue
    omega.add(key)
    L.append((a,b))

print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to keep only the first tuple of each pair:

```
l =[(3,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,2), (3, 3), (5, 6)]

def first_tuples(l):
    # We could use a list to keep track of the already seen
    # tuples, but checking if they are in a set is faster
    already_seen = set()
    out = []
    for tup in l:
        if set(tup) not in already_seen:
            out.append(tup)
            # As sets can only contain hashables, we use a 
            # frozenset here
            already_seen.add(frozenset(tup))
    return out

print(first_tuples(l))
# [(3, 4), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: just a nitpick - the OP mentions that the goal is to "get rid of each second tuple with the same pairing in different order" - I was wondering about the `for fs in set` - it's not guaranteed to provide the first one, is it? (since a set is not ordered...)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this should be both shorter and clearer than anything posted so far:

```
my_tuple_list = [(3,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,2)]

set((left, right) if left < right else (right, left) for left, right in my_tuple_list)

>>> {(2, 3), (3, 4)}
```

It simply makes a set of all tuples, whose members are exchanged beforehand if first member is > second member.

Comment: the notation is indeed quite elegant, but IMHO it's doing something slightly different. The OP mentioned that the goal is to "get rid of each second tuple with the same pairing in different order", i.e., for `[(4,3),(2,1),(3,4)]` produce `[(4,3),(2,1)]`. This code "normalizes" all tuples to `(i,j)` with `i<=j` and also doesn't respect the original order of tuples...